# Debian - Squid перед роутером

Tags: прокси, squid, роутер

Случилась следующая ситуация: есть локалка, роутер в который входит два интернет провайдера(один запасной), этот же раздаёт dhcp. задача следующая в сети надо поднять прозрачный squid, идея собственно посетила такая, воткнуть сервер с suid`ом как шлюз перед роутером и от него давать инет роутеру. подскажите возможны ли какненибудь проблемы при этом, и собственно не возникнут ли костыли с доступом к инету если роутер по прежнему будет раздавать dhcp адреса(крайне не желательно от этого отказываться)?

Comment: гугли transparent прокси, точку доступа делай в режиме bridge, одним концом в LAN сервера другим в WAN точки, в сервер обоих провайдеров заведи. всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сервер со сквидом сделать роутером, а коробочку с антеннкой использовать как свитч + вайфай точка доступа. дешево и сердито.

Comment: благодарю именно так и делаю.

Answer (score 0):

> воткнуть сервер с suid`ом как шлюз перед роутером

А зачем ?

Может вам надо наоборот.

Comment: роутер раздаёт wifi и инет на компы в данный момент. хотелось бы что бы все это дело проходило через squid, и как то мне представляется именно озвученое мной выше решение, если предложите более рациональное буду только рад)

Comment: рациональнее как раз использовать прокси после роутера, но роутер должен стать бриджом.

Comment: Вам надо наоборот, пользователи подключаются к squid  который внутри сети, а squid  идет сам в мнет через рутер. Что бы всех пользователей направить на  squid,  а не через рутер,  вам, либо у пользователей прокси прописать, либо если рутер умеет , создать правило и перенаправлять с него на  squid. Т.е если пользователь не знает о прокси он придет на рутер, а рутер его редиректнет на прокси, а с прокси уже в инет.

Comment: этот вариант тоже рассматривался, но по скольку роутер мягко говоря не торт, то как то возникла именна такая идея, воткнуть шлюз с прокси перед роутером.(роутер будет в скором времени менятся, и настраивать его нет ни какого желания)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, топикстартер путает прокси с роутером. Что не очень удивительно, ибо во многих роутерах уже имеются некоторые функции прокси, как то - фильтрация адресов и ограничения трафика. Интересно бы знать, чего такого не хватает топикстартеру в простом среднестатистическом роутере, что ему ещё и прокси надобно?

Comment: боюсь что вы ошибаетесь .  прокси я желаю установить на шлюз, который и заменит роутер который в данный момент выполняет данную функцию, прокси squid  шлюз поднимать планируется на debian, прокси мне нужен для фильтрации контента в интернете и разграничивания доступа (squid+rejick)